# Why flip function in Pancake Sorting will reverse all element from [0 to k]?

Tags: algorithm, sorting

When I read about Pancake Sorting in Wikipedia:

```
def flip(arr, k):
    left = 0
    while left < k:
        arr[left], arr[k] = arr[k], arr[left]
        k -= 1
        left += 1
def max_index(arr, k):
    index = 0
    for i in range(k):
        if arr[i] > arr[index]:
        index = i
    return index

def pancake_sort(arr):
    n = len(arr)
    while n > 1:
        maxdex = max_index(arr, n)
        flip(arr, maxdex)
        flip(arr, n - 1)
        n -= 1
```

I think we don't need reverse all element from 0 to k, just only swap 0 and k like:

```
def flip(arr,k):
    arr[0], arr[k] = arr[k], arr[0]
```

Because in `pancake_sort` we will loop through all element in `arr`, then reverse element between 0 and k in `flip` is unnecessary.

That's my thinking, can anyone point out where i'm wrong? I have tried many test cases but haven't found my missing

Comment: Just try it with a small example on pen and paper.

Comment: I did, I also rewrite with java, then I see purpose of this flip function is swap biggest element to arr[0] and after that swap to last index

Comment: *"I think we don't need reverse all element from 0 to k, just only swap 0 and k"*: ....but then it isn't a "pancake sort" anymore. By the definition of the sorting method, it *has* to only make such operations. If you touch that, it isn't the same sorting algorithm anymore, and should get a different name.